# How to change default sculpting color?

Tags: sculpting

On many sculpting tutorial videos when they enter sculpt mode their mesh becomes a rich red as in [here](https://youtu.be/6OTX3ZdYvEA?t=174). On mine, it remains in the same black/white layout as in edit mode [here](https://youtu.be/6OTX3ZdYvEA?t=118). It's much easier for me to see gradients on the red so how do I go about changing this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can change the *Viewport Shading* in the top right corner of the 3D editor. Open up the drop-down menu by pressing the upside-down <kbd>^</kbd>, then select *MatCap*. Then, press the ball to change which MatCap you want to use.

[image]

I believe this is the one you're seeing in the video.

[image]

Note that these settings will only be visible if you're in the *Solid Viewport Shading* mode.